# Java: Performance impact of massively concurrent method calls

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a basic question for which I can't find an answer on the net: Assuming I have an application where multiple threads share a single instance of a utility method from which potentially long lasting calculations are triggered.

Is it possible that massively concurent method calls would influence the performence of the methods execution?

EDIT: By *"influence the performence"* I mean: Significantly decreasing execution speed, or even blocking method execution.

Comment: If there are no synchronization blocks, no. The only performance degradation you will see is from thread context switching, but code within the method won't be blocked.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Can you please provide a link to the documentation where that is discussed?

Comment: I don't have such a link. Can you go into more detail about what you mean with _influence the performance_?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ... Significantly decreasing execution speed, or even blocking method execution (updated question as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method is not sharing any resource. Then Not very much (at least not significantly, you will avoid contentions). You will lose performance only in increase garbage collections, CPU usage, Object creations etc, but Thread contentions and Cache Flushing will be less. From Resources i mean Shared Objects, Shared I/O. But In practice it is likely that you will have atleast one shared resources.

But if the method is using some shared resources then yes, that method could be bottleneck.
But there are many patterns by which you can improve the performance. 
For example if many threads only read such a shared resource and only few write/update the 
shared resource then you could use ReadWriteLocks to guard that lock. Or You can use the Actor Pattern -> http://www.slideshare.net/drorbr/the-actor-model-towards-better-concurrency

Also please always try to use Concurrent Data Structures to share your shared resources.
for example ConcurrentHashMap can be used very well to share information among threads.
For producer consumer problems among Threads try using different Implementations of BlockingQueue. These data Structures will also degrade performance but you have to pay the price for accuracy anyways.

Also remember please focus on design of the problem first and then performance. if you get the design right you will have many better ways to improve performance. Remember these are common problems of concurrency and there are already good patterns to overcome many short comings.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, for example if the method uses a shared (or limited) resource.

Such a resource could be a lock, a database connection, a (slow) disk, or even RAM (both the amount of RAM and the available memory bandwidth are limited).

Comment: Such as a database connection?

Comment: @achingfingers: For example. Or a (slow) disk. Or large amounts of memory.

Comment: Can you add one or two links please. Then it will be enough for me to accept your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

The performance could also be decreased by a greater workload for the Garbage Collector that has to clean up objects that are allocated in the method. Although this is not strictly due to concurrency itself (but only due to the method being called very often), it will more likely have an impact in an environment where the time that is available for the GC is already limited by a high number of active threads.